# Can I use an email as a unique identifier for users?

Tags: openid, facebook-oauth, google-openid

Can I use just an "email" as a unique identifier for a website that only supports
Google OpenID and facebook OAuth Login?

I'm not storing IDs, I'm just storing the email...

Will it be enough ? Will there be conflicts?, and will someone who registered a facebook account with that same email of gmail but haven't yet activated it be able to login, and gain access to that of which was registered with OpenId ?

Comment: It's better to store user id's, cause if a user change his/her email address, you will not find them in your users list. You can also store the email and check if a user have change it, so you can update it.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to store user id's, cause if a user change his/her email address,
you will not find them in your users list.
You can also store the user email and check if a user have change it, so you can update it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recomended to use email as unique identifier because facebook users have the option to change the email associated with their account any time. In that situation your system will fail.